# CSS switch between cases

Tags: css, opera

I have this CSS:

```
.opera .lb-overlay:target {
width: auto;
height: auto;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
padding: 8px 400px 12px 400px;
}

.lb-overlay:target {
width: auto;
height: auto;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
padding: 8px 100px 12px 100px;
}
```

what i want to do is this, when its opera do this padding 
 else do other padding ,
 but its not working for me
can anyone  advise me with this
I really appreciate

Regards

Comment: Did you include [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

Comment: Well do you detect in any way if the visitor is using opera? `.opera` is not a class that is added by default or something.

Comment: i am trying the example on opera directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css hack for opera may work for you
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
       #id {css rule} /*put your class or id which you want for opera*/
 }

Comment: this method will detect if the browser is opera and will execute the css ?